GCC+MPICH Link-time optimization generates "inlining failed" warnings for compiler-generated functions
TL;DR: How do I fix* inline failures by LTO on compiler-generated functions?
(* by "fix" I mean "eliminate warnings in a manner consistent with best practice." I want to remove the warning messages, but do so by fixing the appropriate settings, not by simply hiding the warnings.)
I am using GCC and MPICH with link-time optimization and -O3 to compile a high-performance code. At link-time, I get the following inline warnings:
warning: inlining failed in call to ‘__dt_comp ’: call is unlikely and code size would grow [-Winline]

The function __dt_comp is compiler-generated (there are many of these generated with various compiler-generated functions). It seems that the compiler is creating functions and asking for them to be inlined, but the inline directive is not respected by the linker during LTO.
I can confirm that this occurs for:

GCC 13.2.0 / MPICH 4.2.0 under Ubuntu 24.04
GCC 11.4.0 / MPICH 4.0 under Ubuntu 22.04

This does not occur, however for

GCC 9.4.0 / MPICH 3.3.2 under Ubuntu 20.04

I do not want to suppress all inline failure warnings; I only want to avoid warnings when LTO fails on compiler generated functions.
Common fixes and why they do not work here:

Remove inline keyword - this does not work because the functions themselves are compiler generated.
Ignore inline warnings - this does not work because warnings are necessary to check other functions
Increase limit on function inlining - this might be a good thing to do, but is not a long-term fix for the problem.

Unfortunately, a MWE is not feasible since this only occurs with a very large code.

It's not clear what you mean by "fix".  Do you want to force these functions to be inlined, or do you just not want to see warning messages about them?

Edited to clarify. Yes I want to eliminate the warning messages, but they are there for a reason. What is the best practice here?
